# How to get metadata from DMG file in Linux?

Tags: linux, metadata, dmg

I would like to read the whatever metadata there might be in a DMG file. I don't need to actually install it, I just want to read any metadata (commentary, timestamp, manifest, whatever) there might be. I'm working on a Linux system, and I do not have superuser privileges.

I have read that it's possible to read a DMG file by mounting it as a loopback filesystem. Is there a way to do that as an unprivileged user?

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [7z](http://www.7-zip.org/) to first unpack the DMG file, and then again on each partition image. Apart from the actual files there will also be files containing various Mac specific meta data.

Answer (score 0):

requires root privileges :(

```
mount -o loop -t hfsplus image.dmg /path/to/directory/you/want
```

dmgmount [DMG Automounter is a nautilus script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dmgmount/)

dmg2img [dmg to standard (hfsplus) image disk file convert tool](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/)